# How does the battery do work on the electron although the speed of electrons is constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-circuits, work, potential-energy, voltage

In a simple circuit how does the battery do work on the electrons of the wire although their speed is constant .

Imagine I want to take a body which has 5 Newtons weight from the ground to 10 meters above it . I will pull it upwards with its weight and a very little force to make it move then I return to just its weight. now the body is moving with a constant velocity there is no change in momentum(∆p=0) .
The motive force is zero as I consider the body's weight as friction so all my force I put is just to prevent the gravity from accelerating the body downwards. Again the motive force is zero as (F = ∆P/∆T).

Now,work=force times distance. the motive force is zero .
So is there work done on this object to move it.
I thought that if we left this object from 10 metered high above the ground then it would be pulled down by 5 Newtons force and there is no (friction/resistance)(pretending there is no air resistance and is the gravity force is constant).The motive force equals the object's weight here work is done.

Comment: There is resistance. And anyway work is force time displacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about pushing a box on a floor with friction. Once you push with a force to overcome maximum static friction force to get the box moving, all you need is to apply a force equal to the kinetic friction force to keep it moving at constant velocity. You are doing work pushing the box even though the velocity is constant. The energy you put into the box as you  push it at constant velocity does not increase its kinetic energy, but is dissipated as friction heating of the surfaces of the box and floor.

Now think about the electron as the box, and the resistance of the circuit conductor as friction (the analogy is not of course exact, but the idea applies). Even though the drift velocity of the electron is constant,  the battery does work to keep it going against electrical resistance, like we need to do work to keep the box moving at constant velocity against friction resistance. The battery energy winds up as heat dissipated in the resistor, just like the energy of our work on the box winds up as heat.

Hope this helps.